# fixed element changes color for certain class of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fixed button with an icon and text. As you scroll through sections, backgrounds are dark and light. I need to have a class I can apply to multiple sections so the button will change the color of the text and the icon. I can get it to work once with the following code, but I can't make it apply only to that section and re-apply if it comes up again.

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.darken').offset().top - 0) {
        $("#editor-masthead").addClass("go-dark");
    } else {
        $("#editor-masthead").removeClass("go-dark");
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you considered [mix-blend-mode](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/)? ([something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/jkwct6w6/1/))

Comment: Wow! @chazsolo, that is awesome! Not something I've toyed with, now I'm gonna have to waste more than a few hours...

Comment: Can only guess at OP's requirements/design - just note [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode) isn't superb.

Comment: that worked great @chazsolo. Thanks! I tried 'difference' because 'luminosity' wasn't working right away, but 'difference' is pretty amazing, multiple colors depending on the background. Cool bit of CSS I'll be exploring more for sure.

Comment: @MatthewWright I'd note that `mix-blend-mode` isn't very cross-browser-supported at the time of this writing.

Comment: I believe you should be using `$(window).scroll( ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept the script in place because the first section's background has a transparency and the recommended CSS applied the same level of opacity to the button. After that this single line of code did the rest. Very cool!

Thanks again @chazsolo!

```
mix-blend-mode: difference;
```

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer since it seemed to help you - now that you have this here, just let me know and I can remove my answer.

Comment: All set. Thanks again. I've already had a lot of fun playing with this obscure (to me) CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [mix-blend-mode](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/). Provided you can use this, try changing the `mix-blend-mode` paired with `background` and `color` properties to get the desired result.

**Note**: [Browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode) is quite poor, so you'd probably want to provide a fallback for unsupported browsers.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}

section:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #e2ffe3;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #666;
  border: none;
  padding: 6px 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<button>Click Me</button>
```